# I need atleast last 30days milliseconds or last month milliseconds in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2, dayofmonth

I am stuck in functionality which required last month milliseconds or last 30days milliseconds record

Comment: Convert from days to milliseconds?

Comment: @user9088454 yes I need to convert into days from milliseconds but I need milliseconds of last 30days or last month

Comment: @JamesZ I need to show last 30days data from my current date

Comment: That sounds like a normal requirement, but how are milliseconds related to it. Does it have to be exactly 30 days to the millisecond accuracy?

Comment: @JamesZ I need past 30days from the current date please can you help me in that?